# install avr-libc

Tags: apt

I'm using Avr controller for programming into Ubuntu, for that I'm installing library using following command, which gives error

> asphalak@asphalak-HP-Pavilion-11-x360-PC:~$ sudo aptitude  install
>   avr‐libc
>
> Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "avr‐libc"
>
> Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "avr‐libc"
>
> No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
>
> 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not
>   upgraded.
>
> Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
>                                             asphalak@asphalak-HP-Pavilion-11-x360-PC:~$

Comment: Are you looking for [gcc-avr](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gcc-avr)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with "-". Try with:

```
sudo aptitude install avr-libc
```

(Copy and Paste the above in Terminal and Press Enter.